# haskell list maximum by hand

Tags: list, haskell

I do have the following problem:

I get an input (List of Integers) and I do want to output a triple (length of the list, sum of the list, and the maximum of the list).

I do have the following function:

```
lengthSumMax :: Num a => [a] -> (Int, a, a)
lengthSumMax [] = (0, 0, 0)
lengthSumMax x = (length x, sum x, maximum x) --maximum is just a place holder
```

I know that maximum is not working because I do not have Ord in this function. Is there a way with recursion that you can find the highest value of the list "by hand" without using Ord or a helper function?

Comment: If you get a list of `Integer`s, then the signature should be `[Integer] -> (Int, Integer, Integer)`, or you can use `Integral a => [a] -> (Int, a, a)` since `Integral a` implies `Ord a`. Another possibility is to work with an ordering function that determines which is the greatest of the two items.

Comment: Num can be a complex number among others, where it isn't clear how to compare the size. Can you use something more narrow than Num, like Real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way with recursion that you can find the highest value of the list "by hand" without using Ord or a helper function?

The type of the items needs to be a member of the `Ord` typeclass to have a notion of what "the largest of two items" means: the `Ord` typeclass defines functions like `>`, `<`, etc. to determine what item is the largest. `maximum` works with `Ord`, otherwise it makes not much sense to retrieve the maximum value.

Doing this by recursion does not mean the `Ord` type constraint can be dropped. In fact we can implement `maximum`, but still we need a notion of what the largest value is. We can make use of a function, `isLarger` for example, that determines which of the two parameters is the largest items, or returns the largest item.

We can work with recursion here, and make a call for the tail of the list, and then update the items accordingly:

```
lengthSumMax :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> (Int, a, a)
lengthSumMax [] = (0, 0, 0)
lengthSumMax (x:xs) = (…, …, …)
    where (l, s, m) = lengthSumMax xs
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` parts. For these you can use the first element of the list `x`, and the length `l`, sum `s`, and maximum `m` of the rest of the list. Note that your maximum will return `0` for a non-empty list, and thus will always be greater than or equal to zero.